# In Blazor Server, how do I use @if to conditionally display navlinks?

Tags: if-statement, blazor-server-side

net Blazor server application where I want to conditionally hide navlinks dependent on the user. I can generate the code in the code section to obtain the values to compare and check:

```
@code{

private string UserName;
private string Admn;
private string BAdmn;
IEnumerable<ApplicConfs> applicConfs;
IEnumerable<Members> members;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    applicConfs = await ApplicConfsService.ApplicConfsList();
    members = await MembersService.MembersList();
    Admn = applicConfs.First().AppAdmin;
    BAdmn = applicConfs.First().BackAdmin;
    var authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authstate.User;
    var name = user.Identity.Name;
}
```

}

I'm comparing the current user.Identity.Name  with Admn and BAdmn. When I execute the code and debug step by step- it properly retrieves the values to compare.

I want those values to be compared in the layout section above it:

```
    @if (@name == @Admn || @name == @BAdmn)
{



<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Administration</h2>
    <p>
        These links provide you with ability to process various parts of all positions at once
    </p>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="DBProcessing/assignimportancetopositionItems"> Assign Importance To Position Items</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="DBProcessing/assigntimetoPositions"> Assign Time To Positions</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="DBProcessing/calcultateitemFTE"> Calculate Item FTE</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="DBProcessing/calcultateitemImportance"> Calculate Item Importance</NavLink>

</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Set Up</h2>
    <p>
        These  links allow you to populate the setup tables for the application
    </p>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="DescriptionTypes/descriptiontypeslist" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Description Types</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Importance/implist">Importance Levels</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="ItemCategory/itemcategorylist">Item Categories</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="KnowledgeDepth/knowdeplist">Knowledge Depth List</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Textual/textuallist">Textual Information</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="positionsummaryanddetails" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Position Details</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="possummarylist" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Position Summary</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Processes/processeslist">Processes</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="ProductService/prdsrvlist"> Products Services</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="WorkHierarchy/workhierlist">Work Hierarchy List</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="TimeScale/timescalelist">Time Scale</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="ApplicationConfiguration/applicconfslist" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Application Configuration</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Members/memberslist"> Members</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Overlap/tmpoverlaplist">Overlap</NavLink>
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="TaskKnowledge/taskknolist">Task Knowledges</NavLink>



</div>


}
```

What is the proper syntax of the @if condition for this?

Thanking in advance for whatever help can be provided...

Answer (score 0):

never mind- my bad. I had forgotten to declare the name as string in the code section. The conditional hiding worked with the above code after that change